# Xcode 11 beta 4 crashes on loading workspace with an error about more than one cerficate

Tags: xcode, crash, beta

I finally found workaround: Go to Xcode Preferences, tab "Account" and delete all but one developer accounts. I had 2 accounts and deleted the second.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found workaround: Go to Xcode Preferences, tab "Account" and delete all but one developer accounts. I had 2 accounts and deleted the second.